# Published Android App Crashes When Being Opened. android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:

Tags: android, google-signin

I tested my app and it was working fine. I published it and I downloaded it but when I open it, it crashes. Here is the stack trace.

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=ws.study.SignIn }
   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1878)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1545)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4283)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4230)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:842)

   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4567)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4535)

   //On Google Developer Console these were bold
   at ws.study.SignIn.updateUI(SignIn.java:195)
   at ws.study.SignIn.handleSignInResult(SignIn.java:121)
   at ws.study.SignIn.access$100(SignIn.java:28)
   at ws.study.SignIn$1.onResult(SignIn.java:92)
   at ws.study.study.SignIn$1.onResult(SignIn.java:88)


   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpt$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpt$zza.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120
```

This is my Sign In activity. When I launch my app it launches from the Sign In activity. I am using Google Sign In api. When the app opens up it shows the Sign In button and then just crashes.

```
public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SignIn";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private TextView mStatusTextView;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

    // Views
    mStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_textview);

    // Button listeners
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    //findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    //findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    // [START configure_signin]
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    // [END configure_signin]

    // [START build_client]
    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    // [END build_client]


}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}

// [START onActivityResult]
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
// [END onActivityResult]

// [START handleSignInResult]
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
// [END handleSignInResult]

// [START signIn]
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
// [END signIn]

// [START signOut]
private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    updateUI(false);
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
// [END signOut]

// [START revokeAccess]
private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                   updateUI(false);
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
// [END revokeAccess]

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
}


private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        //mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    mProgressDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.hide();
    }
}


private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
    if (signedIn) {
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Intent signInToMain = new Intent("ws.study.MainActivity");
        startActivity(signInToMain);
        //findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signed Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent stayOnSignIn = new Intent("ws.study.SignIn"); //This might be the error
        startActivity(stayOnSignIn); //If user fails to sign in or signs out bring them to sign in activity
        //mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);
        //findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;
        //case R.id.sign_out_button:
            //signOut();
            //break;

    }
}
}
```

I thought the error was because I had log calls in the Sign In activity but I removed the log calls by using this in the proguard-rules.pro:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
public static int v(...);
public static int i(...);
public static int w(...);
public static int d(...);
public static int e(...);
}
```

Here are the activities in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SignIn">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ws.study.MainActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Is my error because in the updateUI function I have an intent to stay on the Sign In activity? Why does the app keep crashing when starting up?

Comment: Did you declare your Activity in the manifest?

Comment: Yes I included the activities in my manifest file. I put an intent filter on the Sign In activity. If the Sign In is successful it goes to the main activity. I put that intent in the updateUI function.

Comment: Where is your internet permission for login api?

Comment: I included the internet permission in the manifest file. I followed the documentation here https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java .

Comment: Minimum and max android version supported? Are you testing on something like M and perhaps you have no runtime permissions? This is kinda hard to tell here

Comment: The minimum android version supported is 4.0-4.0.4. I have been mainly testing on devices that are API level of 23. I am new to developing android apps. This may be a dumb question but if I signed in on the emulator through google and I published the app without signing out, does that mess up the Sign In activity?